# getting data from Textviews in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, view

i am trying to get data from Textviews in a listview after has been modified by the user. 
So then the user click on the row the "descrec" Textview will changed to "completed"

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descrec);
        if(text2.getText().toString().equals("Selected"))
        {
            text2.setText(Outstanding.outDesc[(int)id]);
        }
        else
        {
            text2.setText("Selected");
        }
        Log.i("you selected row number",String.valueOf(id));
    }
});
```

once user finish selecting rows and hit the "submit" button i should print all the rows with "selected" String in "descrec" Textview but it's printing nothing.

```
public void submit (View view)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) 
    {
        v = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        TV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descrec);
        if (TV.getText().toString().equals("Selected"))
        {
            //just to make sure descrec text has beeen changed somewhere
            Log.i("descrec", (String) TV.getText());
        }
        //to check the Textview anyway
        Log.i("descrec value", (String) TV.getText());
    }
}
```

and the result of printing the whole rows' "descrec" giving the original values of the Textview before the user changed it to "Selected".

Here is the results after selecting rows and hitting submit button.

[image]

here is the full code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_outstanding);
        new MyAsync().execute();
    }




    class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i("preexcute","first");
            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewout);
            Contactadapter2 = new contactadapter2(Outstanding.this , R.layout.rowrecord_layout);
            listView.setAdapter(Contactadapter2);




            BackgroundWorker Backgroundworker = new BackgroundWorker(Outstanding.this);
            Backgroundworker.execute(type,Homescreen.userID);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            Log.i("postexcute","second");

            for (int i = 0; i < outrecieptID.length; i++) {
                Log.i("test", valueOf(i) + "out of" + valueOf(outrecieptID.length));

                Contacts2 contacts2 = new Contacts2(Outstanding.outrecieptID[i], Outstanding.outAmount[i], Outstanding.outDesc[i]);
                Contactadapter2.add(contacts2);
            }

            for(int i=0 ; i < listView.getCount() ; i++) {
                v[i] = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
            }

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                    TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descrec);
                    TV = (TextView) v[(int)id].findViewById(R.id.descrec);
                    if(text2.getText().toString().equals("Selected"))
                    {
                        text2.setText(Outstanding.outDesc[(int)id]);
                    }else
                    {
                        text2.setText("Selected");
                        TV.setText("Selected");
                    }
                    Log.i("you selected row number",String.valueOf(id));
                }
            });


        }

    }




    public void submit (View view)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
           // v = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
            TV = (TextView) v[i].findViewById(R.id.descrec);
            if (TV.getText().toString().equals("Selected"))
            {
            //just to make sure descrec text has beeen changed somewhere
                Log.i("descrec", (String) TV.getText());
            }
            //to see the Textview anyway
            Log.i("descrec value", (String) TV.getText());

        }

    }
```

Here is the contactadapter code :

```
public class contactadapter2 extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list= new ArrayList();
    public contactadapter2(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public void add(Contacts2 object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row;
        row=convertView;
        ContentHolder contentHolder;
        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowrecord_layout,parent,false);
            contentHolder = new ContentHolder();
            contentHolder.recieptidout=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.recieptidrec);
            contentHolder.amountout= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.amountrec);
            contentHolder.descout= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.descrec);




            row.setTag(contentHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            contentHolder = (ContentHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Contacts2  contacts2 = (Contacts2) this.getItem(position);
        contentHolder.recieptidout.setText(contacts2.getrecieptidrec());
        contentHolder.amountout.setText(contacts2.getamountrec());
        contentHolder.descout.setText(contacts2.getdescrec());




        return row;
    }

    static class ContentHolder
    {


        TextView recieptidout,amountout,descout;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the model with the "Selected" Text . Otherwise it wont work . Because when you call `v = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null)` It will bind the data from your arraylist . So it will change your text that you set in the itemclick listener.

try to change some thing like this,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descrec);
                if(text2.getText().toString().equals("Selected"))
                {
                    text2.setText(Outstanding.outDesc[(int)id]);
                }
                else
                {
                    text2.setText("Selected");
                }
                Contacts2 contacts2 = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                contacts2.setdescrec(text2.getText().toString());
                Log.i("you selected row number",String.valueOf(id));
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you please explain how can i update the model ??